# CentOS + Apache: You don't have permission to access /info.php on this server

Tags: php, apache, centos7

I have installed CentOS 7 with Apache Web Server and PHP. But when I try to test php I've got this error

[image]

The user and group of info.php are "apache"

[image]

My Document Root is defined like you can see:

[image]

If I try to access with http://localhost it works, but when I try to access with http://localhost/info.php then it fails!!!

I have installed php and php-fpm package. Maybe Would I need other packages?

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit I:**

Looking for an error in access_log file I have found this error:

[image]

Why I get this error?

**Edit II:**

Looking for in error_log file I have found that is a problem of permissions:

```
[Tue Jul 24 18:44:21.084670 2018] [mime_magic:error] [pid 4986] [client ::1:38162] AH01512: mod_mime_magic: can't read `/var/www/html/info.php'
    [Tue Jul 24 18:44:21.084848 2018] [core:error] [pid 4986] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:38162] AH00132: file permissions deny server access: /var/www/html/info.php
```

But the file belongs to "apache" user and group ... :(

[image]

**Edit III:**

[image]

Comment: Look at the server's error log. Does it say why permission was denied?

Comment: "Looking for an error in access_log" — OK. Now look in the *error* log

Comment: By experience this sounds like a selinux issue. Can you try disabling it temporarily to see if it changes anything? `echo 0 > /selinux/enforce`. I can help you with a permanent fix if it really is the issue.

Comment: Sorry but If I write: sudo echo 0 > /selinux /enforce
I've got like answer that I have not permission. How can I do this operation?

Comment: If I try to do this: sudo echo 0 > /selinux/enforce the system tells me that the directory doesn't exists

Comment: Verify that Apache is running under that user, `ps -ef | grep httpd`. Also, verify php-fpm is also configured for the apache user inside `www.conf`.

Comment: Where is the file www.conf? My httpd.conf is inside /etc/httpd/conf/

Comment: I have edited my original post with an screen capture with ps -ef | grep httpd

Comment: For the future, you can use the command `getenforce` to see if SELinux is enabled, and `ls -Z` to show context information. You should not have to disable SELinux to debug. _(oops, from 2018, someone else bumped it to front page)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem is:

```
sudo chcon -R -v -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t info.php
```

How @Lou said it was a SELinux problem.

Answer (score -1):

I was reluctant to disable SELINUX completely. This is what worked for me: restorecon -R /var/www/html/